# Close cefpython clientand restart a new one

Tags: python-3.x, cefpython

During the application flow I would like to close cefpython running client and open a new one; I've this function

```
....
while True:
    settings = {...}
    settings2= {...}
    cef.Initialize(settings=settings)
    self.BROWSER = cef.CreateBrowserSync(url=url,
                                         window_title="Tutorial", 
                                         browserSettings=settings2)

    bindings = cef.JavascriptBindings(bindToFrames=False,
                                      bindToPopups=False)
    bindings.SetFunction("backend", func)
    self.BROWSER.SetJavascriptBindings(bindings)


    cef.MessageLoop()
    cef.Shutdown()
```

and in another function I have this call

```
self.BROWSER.CloseBrowser(True)
```

Browser start on first run and is closed but it does not restart. If I comment the line

```
...
cef.MessageLoop()
#cef.Shutdown()
```

in the first function the browser does restart but it get stuck and I can't use it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Functions like `cef.Initialize` and `cef.Shutdown` can be called only once during app lifetime. You also shouldn't call `cef.MessageLoop` multiple times. Your code `while True` doesn't make much sense, because you do not give browsers time to initialize and load. You should use events like LoadHandler.OnLoadEnd or OnLoadingStateChange or others depending on what you're trying to accomplish.